# File Upload to a folder in Springboot

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, upload

I'm trying to do a simple file upload following the next post:

http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/02/08/spring-boot-file-upload-with-ajax/

Everything works great, but I would like to upload files to a folder created in my spring boot project located in:
src/main/resources/**uploaded_files**

The folder is created in my project.

I've tried with:

Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:");

to get this location, but no way.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a good reason for doing it, saving uploaded files to your src folder (or resources) is not a good practise. Regarding this, to access the files in your resources folder try this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
// Get the resource
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("uploaded_files/filename");
// If you want to use that resources as a File
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("uploaded_files/filename").getFile());
```

Comment: Hi. You code doens't work for me. classLoader is not getting that location (src/main/resources).